# Reload JSON data from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to reload data every 5 seconds using jQuery. The URL for the JSON data can be found at http://gdx.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2015/month_11/day_11/master_scoreboard.json

This is the code I am trying:

```
$.getJSON("http://gdx.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2015/month_11/day_11/master_scoreboard.json", function (json) {
    $.each(json.data.games.game, function (i, value) {

        $('#LMP').append('<div id="equipo"><div class="p1"><img src="img/lmp/' + value.away_name_abbrev + '.png' + '" alt=""></div><div class="p2"><div class="p2-1"> </div><div class="p2-2">' + value.status.inning + ' ' + value.status.top_inning + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="p3"><img src="img/lmp/' + value.home_name_abbrev + '.png' + '" alt=""></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

    });
});
```

Comment: can you explain in little more detail? What exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: That information recharged every 5 seconds to refresh the json information.

Comment: So you can try to enclose this call in a function and call this function using a `setInterval(function, timeInterval)`.

Comment: I can put it like ? I am new to javascript

Comment: you can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval) for reference. Also refer [setInterval - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [setTimeout - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it might look like this:

```
function getJson () {
    $.getJSON("http://gdx.mlb.com/components/game/win/year_2015/month_11/day_11/master_scoreboard.json", function (json) {
        $.each(json.data.games.game, function (i, value) {

            $('#LMP').append('<div id="equipo"><div class="p1"><img src="img/lmp/' + value.away_name_abbrev + '.png' + '" alt=""></div><div class="p2"><div class="p2-1"> </div><div class="p2-2">' + value.status.inning + ' ' + value.status.top_inning + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="p3"><img src="img/lmp/' + value.home_name_abbrev + '.png' + '" alt=""></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

        });
    });
}

var i = setInteval(getJson, 5000);
```